# Is there a inbuilt mechanism so that bytes writen to the pipe can overwrite earlier bytes if buffer is not enough?

Tags: c++, windows, named-pipes

Pretty much like a queue,when the  queue is full an new member wants to come in,just remove the first member at the head of the queue.

Is there such a default mechanism in windows?

If yes how can I do that in c/c++?

Comment: If you control client and server you might consider using UDP - it operates pretty much as you'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Once written, bytes have to be read on the far end before bytes written later on the sending side can be read.  It would not be much of a pipe otherwise.  Any discard would have to be implemented on the receiving side.  Or implement a write queue on the send side and discard as needed if you find yourself blocked on write.

Answer (score 0):

> A WriteFile  operation is affected by
>   the wait mode of a pipe handle when
>   there is insufficient space in the
>   pipe's buffer. With a blocking-wait
>   handle, the write operation cannot
>   succeed until sufficient space is
>   created in the buffer by a thread
>   reading from the other end of the
>   pipe. With a nonblocking-wait handle,
>   the write operation returns a nonzero
>   value immediately, without writing any
>   bytes (for a message-type pipe) or
>   after writing as many bytes as the
>   buffer holds (for a byte-type pipe).

[see](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365605%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)